# JIRA REST API -Get project roles/groups of a user

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

What is the REST call to list all the project roles of a user.

I could get the groups by using:
http://XXX/rest/api/2/user?username=XXX&expand=groups.

I want the project role results by sending username but not project name.

Answer (score 0):

This is not available yet I guess. But It would be helpful if you could post your JIRA-Version anyway.

Only think that might be of interest for you is here: Taken from JIRA 6.1 docs. But you have to define the permissions in this request.

https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/jira/6.1.html

`/rest/api/2/user/permission/search?username&permissions&issueKey&projectKey&startAt&maxResults
Returns a list of active users that match the search string and have all specified permissions for the project or issue.
This resource can be accessed by users with ADMINISTER_PROJECT permission for the project or global ADMIN or SYSADMIN rights.`

The project key is optional for this call.

If this won't help you: 
You can extend the rest API with your own plugin.

Comment: JIRA version is 6.3.14

Comment: this works only for given *issueKey*, not as flat search replacing http://serverip/secure/admin/user/ViewUserProjectRoles!default.jspa call